# How to specify multiple conditions in an 'if' statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Here is how I tried to mention two conditions *if this or this*, but it doesn't work.

```js
if (Type == 2 && PageCount == 0) !! (Type == 2 && PageCount == '') {
    PageCount = document.getElementById('<%=hfPageCount.ClientID %>').value;
}
```

How do I specify multiple conditions in an `if` statement?

Comment: Isn't this question just a typo, one of the reasons for closing questions? Really curious as to why this has so many upvotes...

Comment: This question is being [discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419635/questions-with-simple-syntax-errors).

Comment: Re *"it doesn't work."*: What happens?

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Just add them within the main bracket of the *if* statement like:

```
if ((Type == 2 && PageCount == 0) || (Type == 2 && PageCount == '')) {
    PageCount = document.getElementById('<%=hfPageCount.ClientID %>').value;
}
```

Logically, this can be rewritten in a better way too! This has *exactly* the same meaning:

```
if (Type == 2 && (PageCount == 0 || PageCount == '')) {
```

Answer (score 54):

Here is an alternative way to do that.

```
const conditionsArray = [
    condition1,
    condition2,
    condition3,
]

if (conditionsArray.indexOf(false) === -1) {
    "Do something"
}
```

Or [ES7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#7th_Edition_-_ECMAScript_2016) (or later):

```
if (!conditionsArray.includes(false)) {
   "Do something"
}
```

Comment: As for me - just too complex. If there is no specific reason to do it this way I would suggest using `&&` operator and, if you do not want to write long/multi-line condition inside `if`, put this under a variable.

Comment: I really like this idea.  I ran into a need to add a lot of conditions and this cut down my code a lot.  Much more readable.  Thanks!

Comment: Note that this doesn't short-circuit, if you wanted to do that you would need to pass in functions and use `.findIndex` or `.find`

Answer (score 15):

I am currently checking a large number of conditions, which becomes unwieldy using the if statement method beyond say 4 conditions. Just to share a clean looking alternative for future viewers... which scales nicely, I use:

```
var a = 0;
var b = 0;

a += ("condition 1")? 1 : 0; b += 1;
a += ("condition 2")? 1 : 0; b += 1;
a += ("condition 3")? 1 : 0; b += 1;
a += ("condition 4")? 1 : 0; b += 1;
a += ("condition 5")? 1 : 0; b += 1;
a += ("condition 6")? 1 : 0; b += 1;
// etc etc

if(a == b) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: I see no comments that this is unwise practice, so I think it is save to use. Thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting and mentioning that this only works if all conditions must evaluate to true. In other words, this is another way of writing `AND` but not `OR`.

Comment: This requires all conditions to be (potentially unnecessarily) evaluated - in this way it's like a very inefficient alternative to AND.

Comment: The redundancy calls for a loop of some kind (unless the conditions are totally arbitrary).

Answer (score 10):

The whole `if` should be enclosed in brackets and the `or` operator is `||` and not `!!`, so

```
if ((Type == 2 && PageCount == 0) || (Type == 2 && PageCount == '')) { ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrap them in an extra pair of parentheses and you're good to go.

```
if((Type == 2 && PageCount == 0) || (Type == 2 && PageCount == ''))
    PageCount = document.getElementById('<%=hfPageCount.ClientID %>').value;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes you can find tricks to further combine statements.

Like for example:

```
0 + 0 = 0
```

and

```
"" + 0 = 0
```

so

```
PageCount == 0
PageCount == ''
```

can be written like:

```
PageCount+0 == 0
```

In JavaScript, `0` is just as good as `false`. Inverting `!`, it would turn `0` into `true`:

```
!PageCount + 0
```

For a grand total of:

```
if (Type == 2 && !PageCount + 0) PageCount = elm.value;
```

Comment: This is if you want to make your code as short as possible but it goes against many good practices. Keep your code readable. This answer is cryptic and will induce the next person looking at your code into making some mistake.

Answer (score 3):

```
if((Type == 2 && PageCount == 0) || (Type == 2 && PageCount == '')) {

    PageCount = document.getElementById('<%=hfPageCount.ClientID %>').value;
}
```

This could be one of possible solutions, so 'or' is `||`, not `!!`.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have to many conditions and you want to add them inside **only** **one** **conditional statement**, then you can add the conditions into an array and then construct the conditional statement like so:

```js
let n = 5
let txt = 'hello'

let c = [
  n === 5, 
  n === 4, 
  n === 6,
  txt === 'hello', 
  txt === 'bye'
]

if(c[0] || c[1] || c[2] || c[3] || c[4]){
  document.write('It satisfies ONE or MORE conditions.');
}else{
  document.write('NO conditions have been satisfied.');
}
```

Comment: Yes, that sounds better. What language feature does it take advantage of (I presume *eval* is ***not*** used somehow)?

Answer (score 0):

#### OR operator

```
if ( con1 == True || con2 == True || con3 == True){
     // Statement ...
}
```

#### AND operator

```
if ( con1 == True && con2 == True && con3 == True){
     // Statement ...
}
```

It works on mine :D

Comment: Normally you wouldn't use `con1 == True`, you'd just use `con1`.  When con1 is something like `x == y`.

Comment: Well, given that `True` is not necessarily `true`, maybe it's a variable defined elsewhere?

Comment: Re *"It works on mine"*: Can you be more specific? For example, environment (browser (incl. version) (e.g. [Firefox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox)), [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) (incl. version), build system (e.g. [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler))), etc.), supported ECMAScript version, etc.? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69293829/edit), not here in comments (********* ***without*** ********** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).