# Add more than one v-if with different conditions for one div without duplicate?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, vue.js, vuejs2

I've `div` Vue with more than one different if condition, there is way to add more than one `v-if` in one `<div>`,

Something like that

```
<div v-if="any" v-if="another-any">
</div>
```

I saw this but working as a and condition, not another condition

```
<div v-if="any && another-any">
</div>
```

And also I saw OR condition

```
<div v-if="any || another-any">
</div>
```

But there are 2 or more different conditions in one div?

Comment: The `v-if` directive works pretty much the same way a regular javascript `if` statement works. If you want to add more than two conditions to the directive, use the ways already outlined in your question: `v-if="conditionA && conditionB && conditionC"`.

Comment: `(cond1) || ((cond2) && (cond3))` you can play with it as you want, you should learn more about if conditions in js.

Comment: Okay that's great but it's read as a `AND` not another condition, so it must be `conditionA and conditionB and conditionC` are valid to run statment what if `conditionB` is another condition with different needs? @Padarom

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710442/how-to-specify-multiple-conditions-in-an-if-statement-in-javascript

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by "condition with different needs"

Comment: @Padarom I mean by different conditions, it means we dont need add it as *AND* function like `conditionA && conditionB` no I need to know how to add 2 different condition for one div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your condition is too long to put it inside a `v-if`, just create a computed property:

```
computed: {
   any() {
       return this.isSomething || this.isSomethingElse // || ...
   }

}
```

and then just use it in template: `<div v-if="any">`

Answer (score 2):

Yes. They run differently just within that div:

```
one && other // runs if both return truthy value
one || other // runs if any of them returns truthy value
```

Caution: `another-any` is invalid variable. Variable name cannot contain `dash`.