# Can you use AND and OR in an if statement?

Tags: javascript

The logic I am trying to express is:

- if `condition_1` AND
- either `condition2` OR `condition3` AND
- `condition_4` THEN
- `console.log("THING ONE")`
- OTHERWISE
- `console.log("THING TWO");`

*edit - figured out original issue was in other code whilst writing, so posting answer [Q&A-style](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)*

Comment: Self-answering is encouraged on SO. But, please make sure it is a question that hasn't been asked before. There are hundreds of questions about using multiple conditions in `if`

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it looks like you can, if the `or` condition is in parenthesis, eg:

```js
var logged_in = true;
var author_username = "fred";
var username = "fred";
var is_editor = false;
var is_something = true;


if (logged_in === true && (author_username === username || is_editor === true) && is_something === true) {
  console.log("THING ONE");
} else {
  console.log("THING TWO");
}
```

See also:

[How to specify multiple conditions in an if statement in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710442/how-to-specify-multiple-conditions-in-an-if-statement-in-javascript)

[Which Logic Operator Takes Precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157814/which-logic-operator-takes-precedence)