# IF this === this AND this === this show/hide div Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, listener, onchange

I'm attempting to create an HTML/CSS/JS form to be used offline.

So far, I've created the `show()` and `hide()` for `div` functionality based on a selection.

If `Cloth` & `White` are selected show one `div` but I can't get it to work.

Here is my attempt below:

```js
if ($("#StartSelector").val() == "Cloth") &&
  if ($("#ColourField").val() == "White") {
    $('#Program').show();
    else {
      $('#Program').hide();
    }
  };
```

```css
form {
  max-width: 900px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="StartSelector">What are you washing?</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="StartSelector">
      <option value="no">Select wash option</option>
      <option value="Cloth">Table Cloth & Napkins</option>
      <option value="HeavyDuty">Heavy Duty Work Wear</option>
      <option value="Kitchen">Kitchen Work Wear</option>
      <option value="Bed">Bed Linen</option>
      <option value="Curtains">Curtains</option>
      <option value="Bath">Bath Towels & Robes</option>
      <option value="Uniforms">Uniforms</option>
      <option value="Personal">Personal Clothing</option>
      <option value="Mops">Mops & Cleaning Textiles</option>
      <option value="Low">Filter for low temperatures</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="Colours">
    <label for="ColourDiv">Types of wash.</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="ColourField">
      <option value="no">Select wash option</option>
      <option value="White">White</option>
      <option value="Colours">Colours</option>
      <option value="Delicate">Delicate</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="Program" style="display: none;">
    <img src="Program1.png" alt="Program 1" width="auto" height="400">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How to specify multiple conditions in an if statement in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710442/how-to-specify-multiple-conditions-in-an-if-statement-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I don't understand that.

Comment: It should be `if (condition && condition)` you have `if (condition) && another_if` - which is why you have a syntax error when you run the snippet.  Change to `if ($("#StartSelector").val() == "Cloth" && $("#ColourField").val() == "White") {`  - no `)` after "cloth" and no second `if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:** Thank's [TiiJ7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3178068/tiij7) and [freedomn-m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2181514/freedomn-m) for comments and suggestions

You must search by value and not by `option` text.

The function had an `if` inside an `if` after the `&&` operator so adjustments were needed.

You must have a listener to capture the changes in these `select` and make comparisons.

I assume you have already added the jquery library to your project.

```js
function myFunction() {
  if ($('#StartSelector :selected').val() == 'Cloth' &&
    $('#ColourField :selected').val() == 'White') {
    $('#Program').show();
  } else {
    $('#Program').hide();
  }
}


$(function() {
  $('#StartSelector, #ColourField').on('change', myFunction);
});
```

```css
form {
  max-width: 900px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="StartSelector">What are you washing?</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="StartSelector">
      <option value="no">Select wash option</option>
      <option value="Cloth">Table Cloth & Napkins</option>
      <option value="HeavyDuty">Heavy Duty Work Wear</option>
      <option value="Kitchen">Kitchen Work Wear</option>
      <option value="Bed">Bed Linen</option>
      <option value="Curtains">Curtains</option>
      <option value="Bath">Bath Towels & Robes</option>
      <option value="Uniforms">Uniforms</option>
      <option value="Personal">Personal Clothing</option>
      <option value="Mops">Mops & Cleaning Textiles</option>
      <option value="Low">Filter for low temperatures</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="Colours">
    <label for="ColourDiv">Types of wash.</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="ColourField">
      <option value="no">Select wash option</option>
      <option value="White">White</option>
      <option value="Colours">Colours</option>
      <option value="Delicate">Delicate</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="Program" style="display: none;">
    <img src="Program1.png" alt="Program 1" width="auto" height="400">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why is `includes` needed? There is an option with the literal value `Cloth`

Comment: "firstly..." - `$("select").val()` is the same as `$("select > option:selected")[0].value` - ie it's the `value=` of the selected option, nothing to do with the text, so `.includes` is just confusing:  [confirmation](https://jsfiddle.net/bmscfyw5/)

Comment: secondly, you've completely skipped over the actual issue - OPs incorrect usage of `&&` and quietly fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I made some adjustments to the answers following the suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for this, that makes sense =)
For the next step, would I need to copy and paste the function X amount of times for all the variations or is there a steamlined way of doing this. Not looking for the solution, just a steer in the right direction.