# How would I write this if else statement correctly?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have written a program where there are three dice and 3 players. Player 1 rolls die 1, player 2 rolls die 2, player 3 rolls die 3. Whoever rolls the highest number (1-6) is the winner. I cannot figure out how to correctly write the if-else statement to correctly display who is the winner. Some code I have tried is:

```
    if (randomNumber1 > randomNumber2 || randomNumber3) {
    document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Player 1 Wins! ";
    }
    else if (randomNumber2 > randomNumber1 || randomNumber3) {
    document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Player 2 Wins! ";
    }
    else if (randomNumber3 > randomNumber1 || randomNumber2) {
    document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Player 3 Wins! ";
    }
    else {
    document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "No Winner!";
    }


    if (randomNumber1 > randomNumber2 && randomNumber3) {
    document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Player 1 Wins! ";
    }
    else if (randomNumber2 > randomNumber1 && randomNumber3) {
    document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Player 2 Wins! ";
    }
    else if (randomNumber3 > randomNumber1 && randomNumber2) {
    document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Player 3 Wins! ";
    }
    else {
    document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "No Winner!";
    }
```

So far these have not worked. Occasionally the program is correct as the highest roll is the winner, other times, for example, player 1 will have a 5 and player 3 will have a 6 and it tells me player 1 is the winner which is clearly not true. What am I missing? Please help. I am new to coding and I have been trying to figure this out all day. The best way for me to understand your answer is to please write out the correct code formatting for me. Please feel free to copy and edit the code I have already made.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to specify multiple conditions in an if statement in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710442/how-to-specify-multiple-conditions-in-an-if-statement-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if (randomNumber1 > randomNumber2 && randomNumber1 > randomNumber3) {
    document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Player 1 Wins! ";
    }
    else if (randomNumber2 > randomNumber1 && randomNumber2 > randomNumber3) {
    document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Player 2 Wins! ";
    }
    else if (randomNumber3 > randomNumber1 && randomNumber3 > randomNumber2) {
    document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Player 3 Wins! ";
    }
    else {
    document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "No Winner!";
    }
```

So what you had wrong is the if statement. The && doesnt mean that the 1st parameter is gonna be compared with both of the others, it means that 2 comparisons need to be true for the if statement to go through.

Also dont forget to check if 2 or all players have the same result and thats the highest number.

Comment: @MJGM Don't forget to accept the answer so others know it helped you if they have a similar issue.